# Showing indexed/sorted DS.hasMany

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to figure out the proper way to display arrays of objects, indexed by the objects' unique 'categoryName' attribute, but the way I'm currently trying to do it is not behaving as I'd expect it to.

```
LO.List = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  items: DS.hasMany('LO.Item'),

  categoryNames: function() {
     // return an array of all unique item.categoryNames
  }.property('items.@each.isLoaded')
});

LO.Item = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  categoryName: DS.attr('string')
});
```

In my templates, I'm trying to loop through each categoryName, render it, and then render all the items in that category.

```
<ul>
    {{#each content.categoryNames}}
        <li>
          Category: {{this}}

          Items: {{view LO.ItemsInCategoryView categoryNameBinding="" itemsBinding=""}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

I'm doing something wrong with my bindings to the ItemsInCategoryView, since I cannot get either the current contextual categoryName or the entire array of Items inside that view.

Fiddling: [http://jsfiddle.net/6ph42/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/6ph42/1/)

Is there a different way I should be doing this? If not, which bindings should I be passing to the view here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a more elegant way, but I think you have to create a new data structure to accomplish what you want.

You could create it on the fly though:

```
categories: function() {
  var categories = [],
      items = this.get('items');

  items.forEach(function(item) {
    var categoryName = item.get('categoryName');

    var category = categories.filterProperty('name', categoryName);
    if(category.length === 0) {
        category = Ember.Object.create({name: categoryName, items: []})
        categories.addObject(category);
    }else{
         category = category.get('firstObject');   
    }
    category.get('items').addObject(item);
  });

  return categories;
}.property('items.@each.isLoaded')
```

I updated your jsfiddle accordingly:

http://jsfiddle.net/6ph42/3/

Comment: Cool - that should work for now. Hopefully someone can pipe in with a yet more elegant solution later. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I started working on a more elegant solution using an ArrayController for categories (which should probably be its own model) and sortProperties on this new CategoriesController (from [Ember.SortableMixin](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html), which is built into ArrayControllers.)

```
LO.CategoriesController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['categoryName'],
  sortAscending: true,
});
```

I also demonstrated how you would use an outlet in your list view to separate listing categories from the list template itself. There is more work to be done here, but in general you will find that the more you can separate concerns and decompose views and models into the smallest possible components, Ember will start making more sense.

http://jsfiddle.net/hNmBF/1/

Sorry that I couldn't finish, I think we either need to see your real application, or a cleaner example (although I understand that is easier said than done, so I'm not getting on your case, I really do want to help). This was a bit too much to wrap my head around in less than 20 minutes.

Comment: Great! That will certainly get me headed in the right direction.